# what is the meaning of "High D"?

Tags: meaning

Whtat is the meaning of "High d"?

If people say " So, I am a High D and...." what is the meaning of "High D"?

I guess this is negative meaning..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Grading scale??

Comment: It doesn't mean anything to me. What is the context?

Comment: Music scale is what popped to my mind...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be jargon related to a certain personality classification system, the "DiSC profile"; it means "high dominance".  Someone who is "High D" is described as a "person [who] places emphasis on accomplishing results, the bottom line, confidence."  See https://www.discprofile.com/what-is-disc/overview/

Comment: Keep in mind this is only in the direct context you've asked, though. If someone says "I got a High D", it might be more likely to mean "I got a high distinction on that test!" In other scenarios there may well be other meanings of D, although I'd agree with Hugh that the DISC personality profile is likely the more common usage.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I think they are talking about the DISC personality profile, but thanks, this site is great,so many nice and smart people and willing to help for non-native speaker.